# Web Api OData Query for custom type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I've defined my own struct that represents `DateTime` with `TimeZoneInfo` so I can work with UTC time while keeping the information about timezone.

I would like to get these objects with OData query, but it fails when I try to use `$orderby` on this properties of this type. I was able to get results when I queried `$orderBy=Timestamp/Value/UniversalTime` but I would like to use just `$orderBy=Timestamp`

Is there any possibility to order collection with this type?

```
public struct DateTimeWithZone : IComparable<DateTime>, IComparable<DateTimeWithZone>, IFormattable
{
    private readonly DateTime _utcDateTime;
    private readonly TimeZoneInfo _timeZone;

    public DateTimeWithZone(DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
    {
        if (timeZone == null)
        {
            throw new NoNullAllowedException(nameof(timeZone));
        }

        _utcDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        _timeZone = timeZone;
    }


    ...
}
```

With model defined like this:

```
public class ClientViewModel
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public DateTimeWithZone? Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how it is used:

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetAll(ODataQueryOptions<ClientViewModel> options)
    {
        var fromService = _clientsClient.GetAllClients().MapTo<ClientViewModel>(MappingStrategy).AsQueryable();
        var totalCount = fromService.Count();
        var results = options.ApplyTo(fromService); // <-- Fails here

        return Ok(new PageResult<ClientViewModel>(
            results as IEnumerable<ClientViewModel>,
            Request.ODataProperties().NextLink,
            totalCount));
    }
```

Fails with `The $orderby expression must evaluate to a single value of primitive type.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we had some similar issue with complex type ordering. Maybe this can be of assistance in your scenario as well. In our case (which is not 100% identical) we use a two phase approach:

1. Rewriting ODataQueryOptions
2. separating the extneral model (ODATA) and the internal model (EntityFramework in our case)

## Rewriting ODataQueryOptions

You mention that the format `$orderBy=Timestamp/Value/UniversalTime` is accepted and is processed properly by ODATA. So you can rewrite the value basically by extracting the `$orderby` value and reinserting it with in your working format.

I described two ways on how to do this in my post [Modifying ODataQueryOptions on the fly](https://d-fens.ch/2017/02/26/modifying-odataqueryoptions-on-the-fly/) (full code included), which take existing options recreate new options by constructing a new Uri. In your case you would extract **Timestamp** from `$orderBy=Timestamp` and reinsert as with `$orderBy=Timestamp/Value/UniversalTime`.

## Separating External and Internal Model

In addition, we used two models for the public facing API and the internal / persistence layer. On the internal side we used different properties which we grouped into a navigation property (which only exists on the public side). With this approach the user is able to specify an option via an `$expand=VirtualNavigationProperty/TimeZoneInfo` and `$orderby=...`. Internally you do not have to use the complex data type, but keep using `DateTimeOffset` which already holds that information. I described this separation and mapping of virtual navigation properties in the following post:

- [Separating your ODATA Models from the Persistence Layer with AutoMapper](https://d-fens.ch/2017/02/22/separating-your-odata-models-from-the-persistence-layer-with-automapper/)
- [More Fun with your ODATA Models and AutoMapper](https://d-fens.ch/2017/02/23/more-fun-with-your-odata-models-and-automapper/)

According to your question it should be sufficient to rewrite the query options in the controller as you did mention that the (little bit longer) `$orderby` format is already working as expected and you only wanted a more convenient query syntax.

Regards, Ronald

Comment: While this answer is quite useful, I wonder if there is not better way to model this. Have you ever found a different approach to make it so that the custom type "becomes a basic type" in OData? Perhaps creating a custom EDM type to support it? Modifying the query looks very hacky to me.

Comment: @julealgon I have never found anything better than described above, but must admit that I stopped researching after having a (for me) working solution. As the original post dates back quite some time, I would probably investigate in ODATA v4 to see if there is better support for custom types.

Comment: I raised a question on GitHub to discuss this with the OData team. https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/1967